# How to conditionally display message if there are no v-for items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I am using Vue with Fullcalendar and am displaying a sidebar of events if the month the user is on has dates associated with it. So i have,

```
 <div v-for="event in events"> etc etc </div>
```

How can I leverage v-if and v-else to conditionally display a message like "Sorry there are no events for this month" if there are none to show?

Something like

```
 <div v-if="events">
      <div v-for="event in events"> etc etc </div>
 </div>
 <div v-else>Sorry there are no events</div>
```

Apologies for the pseudo code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly like in your example, but add length checking:

```
<div v-if="events && events.length > 0">
      <div v-for="event in events"> etc etc </div>
</div>
<div v-else>Sorry there are no events</div>
```

Comment: Definitely seems like that should work but it's showing the v-else message alongside the v-for items. Weird.

Comment: is there any other `v-if` in your code? maybe `v-else` is matching with this other `v-if`

Comment: @yerme - This code should work provided that `events` is defined and has a non-zero length. `console.log`ing verifies that this is the case?

Comment: @PaulBovis I needed to nest the v-if deeper in my markup; the code worked it was just how I had it set up that needed a tiny tweak. All good.